# Cannot properly rotate a translated UIView on the iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation

I have an `UIViewController` that has two UIViews inside, whose layout (set in Interface Builder) is something like this (the magenta colored view is the UIViewController default view):

[image]

and I added the main view to a root view obtaining this effect (by not showing the darker view placing its `frame` at the bottom):

[image]

Now when the device rotates, what I obtain is this:

[image]

whereas I'd like to still hide the darker view.
This is the code I use to hide it when it appears (I use it in the `viewDidLoad` method):

```
- (void)hideAll:(float)time{
        CGRect hiddenFrame = CGRectMake(0, 1024, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [self.view setFrame:hiddenFrame];
        [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

and it appears to work, but when I call a variant of it when rotating (in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`), nothing happens:

```
    CGRect hiddenFrame = CGRectMake(0, 748, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view setFrame:hiddenFrame];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

What am I missing? have I to set some other view property in Interface Builder?

**UPDATE**

It seems to me that the coordinate system does not change after the device has been rotated (ie the origin set in the upper-left corner in portrait mode will become the upper-right after a clockwise rotation in landscape mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I encountered can be faced in two ways (I hope this can save some time for someone in the future):

- using an UIViewcontroller (loaded from xib) and only its view as the rotating view, that is my original attempt to solve it. In this case you have to programmatically set the frame for the view when you want to hide it, and by doing so you have to consider that the coordinate system for the controller remains untouched and does not rotate (ie. it is always originated from the same corner)
- using a UIView (loaded from xib) inside an already existing UIViewcontroller, in this way the view will automatically rotate and resize and you will not have to take the proper coordinates value into account at each rotation (this is by far the simplest way)

Answer (score 1):

Check your struts and springs in IB. It maybe that when you autorotate, the strut fixing you to the top of the screen moves your frame back to the top.

Try adding your code to the didRotateToInterfaceOrientation method so it can run after rotation has occurred.

Comment: I have no struts in IB, just two springs for the darker view (so I guess the problem does not lie here). When I implement the `didRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` it changes appearance but it seems that the coordinate system does not change, it remains fixed to the old corner. Is this behaviour correct?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no Mac to hand so I can't check.  But, from memory, the new coordinate system should be in effect once `didRotateToInterfaceOrientation` has been called.  So if the screen was previously (0,0,1024,768) it should now be (0,0,768, 1024).  I am wondering about the self.view.frame.size.width / height calls - shouldn't these actually be the screen size and height obtained through `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]`.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that it seems that the origin corner is still the same even after the device rotated, ie if in portrait mode it is the upper-left one, after a 90 degree rotation clockwise it is the upper-right!

Answer (score 0):

Why to you change the frame to hide it, and not just

```
[self.view setHidden:YES];
```

second thing is that you should try to set the "Autoresizing" panel to handle the orientation changes, and not by changing the frame of the view.

hope i understood you right.

shani

Comment: I do not need to hide the whole view, but just to move it down so that only the **upper part** is visible (in this way it can be dragged up)